# Sticky footer after complete scroll

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky

I am trying to create a "see-also" button that is located on the bottom of the page. 
When the user reaches the bottom and decides to scroll back up, I want it to stick to the bottom of the viewport.

I have been trying with `position:sticky` but then it is already sticked to the bottom of the viewport when the page just loaded. I only want this after a complete scroll down.

Any clues? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course. A sticky element's position is always inside the viewport. Maybe what you need is JavaScript code that makes the button appear once the user has scrolled down enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrambled everything together and this is working now:

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
  if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
    document.getElementById("see-also").classList.add("sticky");
  }
};
```

Thanks you everyone

Answer (score 2):

This is an example with javascript (see result [sticky button on scroll top](https://plnkr.co/plunk/6TuuFbZMa2z2ousD)

```
const DIRECTION_BOTTOM = 1;
const DIRECTION_TOP = 0;

let previousScroll = 0;
let direction = scrollY === 0 ? DIRECTION_BOTTOM : DIRECTION_TOP;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    const scrollY = window.scrollY;

    if(direction === DIRECTION_TOP && previousScroll < scrollY){
        direction = DIRECTION_BOTTOM;

        // remove sticky
        document.getElementById("sticky").classList.remove("show");
    }
    else if(direction === DIRECTION_BOTTOM && previousScroll > scrollY ){
        direction = DIRECTION_TOP;

        // Add sticky 
        document.getElementById("sticky").classList.add("show");
    }

    previousScroll = scrollY;
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Almost there. Now I just need to have the class added when I reach the bottom of the page and not on scroll direction.

Comment: Update this code : remove direction, and if condition

Answer (score 0):

You can create this functionality with JQuery by creating a function which calculates when an element is in the viewport. If the button enters the viewport, add a class which makes the element position: sticky. There are different ways to approach this problem but one solution is something like this:

```js
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};
  

  
 $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($('#button').isInViewport()) {
        $('#button').addClass('sticky');
    }
 });
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

.div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  color: #fff;
}

.div1 {
  background: blue;
}
.div2 {
  background: red;
 }
 .div3 {
  background: purple;
 }
 
 .sticky {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="div div1">Filler div 1</div>
<div class="div div2">Filler div 2</div>
<div class="div div3">Filler div 3</div>

<button type="button" class="button" id="button">See Also</button>
```